# Changing Isolation Level in SSMS Options via PowerShell\Registry

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, ssms

I'm wondering if there is a powershell or registry settings that can be used to change the Transaction Isolation Level in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)?

I'm trying to force users who have SSMS installed to always use Read Uncommitted without having to walk around to everyone's workstation to manually set this.

I've found some good resources online discussing this program from a server perspective but they all agree that it won't work out as expected.

Thanks,
P

Comment: Why? This seems like a very very very bad idea. Why do you want to force every single query in SSMS to be forced to used read uncommitted. Are you ok with the accuracy of  every query being potentially wrong? You can and will get missing and/or duplicated rows, possibly even entire pages when you do this. Remember this is the same thing as putting NOLOCK on every single table. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: Sean, thanks for your reply. In summary... yes I am OK with such potential issues with the accuracy of the data.  The underlying goal here is to prevent locking issues with UI accessing the DB.

Comment: Using read uncommitted is NOT the way to handle this. You are trying to fix the symptom instead of the cause. You need to fix the queries and reduce/eliminate the locking issue.

Comment: You are absolutely correct this is only treating the symptom. There is a larger project to fix the underlying issue.  This will prevent deadlocks until then.

Comment: Yikes. You are planning on using this for updates, inserts and deletes too? Did you read that article I posted? You are highly likely to end up corrupting your indexes. Also, you are likely going to receive other errors regarding data movement. Seems like you are talking about an application level setting here, not SSMS. AFAIK there isn't a way to do this.